# How to traverse C loop correctly using File Pointer only

Tags: c, file, loops, pointers, while-loop

I am making a program in c that reads line by line and does some operation on the elements of every line. I am calling my read_row function like this.

```
while(filePointer!=NULL)
{
        int result=readRow(filePointer,headerRow,lineRow);
        printf("The value of  row is |%d|\n",result);
}
```

Inside my read_row function I am using get c to traverse through the line.

```
 cc=getc(fp);
    while((cc!='\n') && (cc!= EOF))
    {

            *line=cc;
            line++;  
            if(cc==',')
            {
                counterr++;
            }
            cc=getc(fp);

    }  

    if(cc==EOF)
    {
        fp=NULL;
    }
```

I am trying traverse through all the lines. However, this loop is infinite as file pointer never goes to null. I have tried to set the file pointer to null if the cc equals to EOF. However, this did not help at all. Therefore, please explain how should I properly terminate that loop. I believe that '\n' is coming before the EOF.Therefore, the file pointer is not getting to null. I have to do it using the file Pointer, as I have already made a very big program based on that logic. Moreover, I could only find examples that used methods like fgets() to traverse.

Comment: show function definition.

Comment: If your logic is based on ending when `filePointer` is `NULL`, how are you going to `fclose` it?

Comment: the function definition requires FILE *. I did not even think about fclose(). Is there any better way to tackle this issue? I can create another copy of filepointer and call fgets.  Both corresponds to the same file both will former will be able to terminate the latter.

Comment: Use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if your system has it

Comment: filepointer is the name of a variable, and until now, there's no chance for a variable to change values, as a result of reading something in C, except for the destination storage where the read value is being done.  Perhaps you are trying to imagine something that works like this in other languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass a pointer to the function and then change it, you are actually changing the copy of that pointer, not the pointer itself. You need to pass a pointer to pointer for this to work, here's a small example:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;

//note the pointer to pointer:
void foo(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = &b;
}

int main() {
    int * ptr = &a;
    foo(&ptr);
    printf("%d", *ptr); // prints 5
}
```

So in your case the `readRow` should accept `FILE**`, and you should call it as `readRow(&filePointer...`

Comment: thats what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function to try：

```
fscanf(fp,"%s\n",out_buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

the posted code has several significant errors.

For instance setting the parameter `FILE* fp = NULL; is only changing the copy of the actual fp, not the fp back in the calling function.

after the `FILE * fp` parameter is changed to `FILE **fp` and the call to the function is modified to match:

before modifying the fp, pass that parameter to `fclose(*fp)`  otherwise the file is still open but the pointer to the associated file descriptor is destroyed, so the file cannot be closed.